# Properly overlapping the end-marker on the path

Tags: javascript, svg

[Updated picture including (c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K605A.png)

I am using the following code in Javascript to generate an end-marker (a triangular arrow) attached to a line:

```
edge.marker('end', 10, 10, function (add) {
add.path('M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2').fill('black');});
```

The above code generates an arrow that looks like (a) in the attached picture. However, the marker (triangle) extends the line. I would like to generate an arrow as shown in (b) with the pointed end of the marker aligned with the end of the line (and not extend it). Also, it should not look like a triangle as in (a), but an arrow as in (b).

I have tried several variations of the code shown in the description with different values, but they all extend the line, which is not desirable in the image I am generating.

Provided in the description.[Picture of actual(a) and desired(b) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEnKH.png)

Comment: You may need to use `refX` and `refY` to defines the  coordinates for the reference point of the marker. If this doesn't help please add your code

Comment: @enxaneta, the following attribute values partially help solve the problem. I can now properly align the arrowhead as shown in (c). However, is there a way to get rid of the base of the arrowhead so it displays as the sample in (b)?

    edge.marker('end', 22, 13, function (add) {
        add.path('M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2').fill('none').stroke('black');
    });


See the picture in c.

Comment: @Learner To make the arrow correctly displayed, like in the `b` picture try adding my recommendations in the answer below.

Comment: Try using this `'M2,10 L10,6 L2,2'` instead of `'M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2'`

Comment: @enxaneta: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I would accept your answer, but it shows up as a comment and does not give me an option to accept.

Comment: Thank you @Learner. I've added an answer where I'm using several other useful attributes for the `<marker>` I hope you'll find it interesting.

Comment: FWIW, I believe this will only work for horizontal lines, not paths, in general. `refX` and `refY` adjust relative to the end of the path; there is no general `refS` which moves the marker "backwards / forwards" along the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is the result of several comments I've exchanged with the OP. In order to place a marker where you need on a path you may use the `refX` and `refY` attributes to define the coordinates for the reference point of the marker.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:45%}
path{fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:2}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="12" markerHeight="12" refX="10" refY="6" orient="auto" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
 fill="none" stroke="black">
<path  d="M2,10 L10,6 L2,2" />
</marker>
  <path d="M20,25 H80"  marker-end="url(#arrow)" />  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

- `fill ="none"` remove the black color inside the arrow..
- add `stroke="black"`
- To prevent lines from changing their thickness, you can also use the
  attribute `path` `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`